Incrementing int passed by reference C++
int x = 0;

incrementX(&x);

x has unexpected results at this point
void incrementX(int* x)
{
     // value in x stays 0
     *x++;

    // value increments each time 1,2,3 ...
    *x+=1;
}

Why is *x++ not the same as *x+=1?

Its because of operator precedence. The first expression could be read as *(x++) and the second as (*x)+=1.

Note that you're using pointers, not references

Realize that not all languages use identical precedence rules.  When in doubt, put in the parentheses - it never hurts (sure, the compiler knows the rules, but aren't we writing code first for HUMAN understanding???).  How many silly PEMDAS postings do we see online that we roll our eyes because EVERYONE thinks they are "right" and everyone else is "wrong".

If the code actually passed by reference this problem wouldn't occur. Don't use pointers unless they're the only way to approach a problem. void increment(int& x) { x++; } will do exactly what you're looking for.

@franji1 -- ((Human understanding) is (not necessarily) (improved (by (redundant) parentheses))). When in doubt, learn the rules.

(*x)++ is the same as (*x)+=1.  Thank you all for responding.

In C++ it's usual to say "pass by reference" by using the language feature of references, and "pass by pointer" for passing by reference via use of pointers

@PeteBecker I had vicious LISP flashbacks now

This question is similar to: Incrementing pointer not working. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Pointer expressions: *ptr++, *++ptr and ++*ptr

This has nothing to do with pass by reference. Here you're passing the pointer by value.

Your example question should have two separate functions: incrementVersion1 that demonstrates using *x++;  and then incrementVersion2 that demonstrates using *x+=1;.  Otherwise it looks like a problem might be caused by modifying the pointer.  Of course, you probably don't realize that's happening to have made asked the question this way, but in general - for your next question - isolate your examples.

I hope that only one of these two statements
 // value in x stays 0
 *x++;

// value increments each time 1,2,3 ...
*x+=1;

is present in the function when it is called. Otherwise the code will invoke undefined behavior.
As for your question then due to the operator precedence this expression statement
*x++;

is equivalent to
*( x++ );

because postfix operators have a higher precedence than unary operators.
The result of the subexpression x++ is the value of the pointer x before the increment of the pointer. So actually the full expression just dereferences the value of the passed pointer.
To achive the expected behavior just rewrite the statement the following way
++*x;

or by means of parentheses like
( *x )++;

Also bear in mind that passing an object by reference in C++ means the following
int x = 0;

incrementX( x );

//...

void incrementX(int &x)
{
    ++x;
}


In the first example you increment the address in the second the value on the memory location points.

Due to the higher precedence of unary postfix operator over unary dereference operator, your function below,
void incrementX(int* x)
{
    // value in x stays 0
    *x++;

    // value increments each time 1,2,3     ...
    *x+=1;
}

is the almost same as the following:
void incrementX(int* x)
{
    // value in x stays 0
    x++; //this only increments the temp value of *, no effects at all after going out of scope
    *x;  //this does nothing

    // value increments each time 1,2,3     ...
    *x+=1;
}

However, if you check what exactly *x++ does, the printf("*x = %d\n", *x++); shows this below:
int *old = x;
x++;
printf("*x = %d\n", *old); //value printed is before x++

As you see, your first statement *x++ does nothing overall after out of scope. But, it will have impact on the outcome of next statement *x+=1;, and makes it not able to change the value of global `x'.
